# Lazy loading carousel

Tags: android, carousel

I fetch the link of some images and then I want to put them in a carousel like image below. It must be lazy loading. Prior to loading the images, a substitute image will be used, then after loading images (from url) they will be replaced.

There are some carousel codes but I couldn't find lazy loading one.[image]

Comment: learn from this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: you can use this https://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/wiki/Carousel.